# How to set DateType range from selected date to current date?

Tags: php, symfony, date-range, formbuilder

I want to create for that lets select year and month. Current solution doesn't work, I cuts all months to `7`, as current month at this time of post is "7".

```
 $builder->add(
        'filter_date',
        DateType::class,
        [
            'format' => 'yMd',
            'years' => range(
                (new DateTime('2013-01-01'))->format('Y'),
                (new DateTime())->format('Y')
            ),
            'months' => range(
                (new DateTime('2013-01-01'))->format('m'),
                (new DateTime())->format('m')
            ),
            'days' => [1],
            'placeholder' => [
                'year' => '----',
                'month' => '----',
                'day' => false,
            ],
            'required' => true,
        ]
    )
```

How to make all years before to have 12 in month selection, and in current year, it won't be able to pick future months?

Comment: I didn't understand anything, can you rephrase ?

Comment: In my form I want to select year from `2013` to `2018` and month selection for full year range is from `1 to 12`, 
for current year, month range from `1 to 7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is cause you are defining your interval for your month from january to the month of the current date with the awkward expression

```
range(
                (new DateTime('2013-01-01'))->format('m'),
                (new DateTime())->format('m')
            )
```

What about

```
'months' => range(1,12)
```

and simple for years if you want to go 5 years back

```
'years' => range(date("Y")-5, date("Y"))
```

or if you want 2013 as fixed start

```
'years' => range(2013, date("Y"))
```

?

The rendering of the input values is happened on the server side, so you are not able to dynamically add/remove values from the input. 
If you still want to use separated input values for choosing a date you have to write JS code your own to replace values dynamically.

If you agree with a datepicker, you could use the following approach.

```
'widget' => 'single_text',
'attr' => array(
        'max' => date('Y-m-d')
    )
```

Comment: `years` are ok with my code. Problem is with months I want it to use `range (1,7)` in current year, but `range(1,12)` for previous year.

Comment: You could probably go with Jim Panse' solution and just deal with the extra months with javascript. Just hide months 8 --> 12 if the current year has been selected. And to be consistent you could have a look at symfony's form events.

Comment: So simply said: You want to block dates after the current month ?